# bitbucket ssh requires git@bitbucket.org's password

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

So I generated a ssh key and added it to bitbucket, then when I "ssh -T git@bitbucket.org" in the terminal, it requested the "git@bitbucket.org's password".
This problem did not arise on my laptop (ubuntu 20) which was connected to the internet via the same local network.
I have checked /etc/hosts, HTTP_PROXY, etc. which are all clear, showing nothing related to bitbucket.
I restarted the computer several times to no avail.
I ensured that only one ssh server was running.
What could be wrong with my desktop (ubuntu 22)?

Edit 1:
Here is the output of ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org

```
(base) pi@pi:~/Downloads$ ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/pi/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/pi/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for bitbucket.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/bitbucket type 3
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/bitbucket-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:zBaRJxidxS95rF36rYX+4dVY8vxsPFXeTaoe/jY0l5o
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 2 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/bitbucket ED25519 SHA256:UuoiiBi82VGqZKqrN1DpeWADDFK14fhaxqxWlEn3JSQ explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: my@email.address ED25519 SHA256:MSZGD5k5hgQ5iHLH+50Tgca9IjupA4Zvr50NxRR6JaE agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/pi/.ssh/bitbucket ED25519 SHA256:UuoiiBi82VGqZKqrN1DpeWADDFK14fhaxqxWlEn3JSQ explicit agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: my@email.address ED25519 SHA256:MSZGD5k5hgQ5iHLH+50Tgca9IjupA4Zvr50NxRR6JaE agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@bitbucket.org's password:
```

Edit 2:
I have double checked that I pasted the content of bitbucket.pub to the ssh key added to my bitbucket account. Since I am using ed25519 scheme, the content is fairly short, like `ssh-ed25519 ASXAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5MAAAIAi+AtlfwCRjTFEAORlZsj96TFGKhWDAXlvgflhaqr1L my@email.address`. The private key is much longer like

```
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZW
QyNTUxOQMAACAIvgLZX8AkY0xSADkZWbI/ekxRioVgwF5b4H5YWqq9lwAJAJis7Hv3rOx7
9wAAAAtzc2gtZWQyNTUxOQAAACAIvgLZX8AkY0xRADkZWbI/ekxRioVgwF5b4H5YWqq9lw
AAAEC3+U4odV1//Kljf1SOWrdJUwqUFC+VkTV6aweA6nWCtAi+AtlfwCRjTFEAORlZsj96
TFGKhWDAXlvgsrhaqr2XAAAADln1YWkuM0Bvc3UuZWR1AQIDBAUGBw==
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Note for security, both keys have been aliased.

Comment: The server doesn't accept private key. Please make sure you uploaded `/home/pi/.ssh/bitbucket.pub` to your account at BitBucket and it's not cut or damaged (a public key is a long file).

Answer (score -2):

I think one possible solution is to restart the computer.

Comment: That's completely bogus.